# Exporting a dictionary to a text file in this format

Tags: python, file, dictionary, writetofile

I am trying to export a dictionary to a text file as shown with the code below:

```
user_scores = {}

with open('Class 1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        this_line = line.strip().replace("\n","").split(",")
        user_scores[this_line[0]] = this_line[1:]

    username = "Andy.Singh"
    score = 25

    user_scores[username] = score

    print(user_scores)

    for user,score in user_scores:
        f.write(user + ',' + score)
```

The text file for Class 1.txt is shown so far:

```
Bob.Smith, 10, 20, 30
```

Here, the dictionary `user_scores` is having the username and scores of `Bob.Smith` written to it. I am also writing another new name, `Andy.Singh` who obtained a score of `25`.

When I run the code, the dictionary writes the dictionary correctly as shown:

```
{'Andy.Singh': 25, 'Bob.Smith': [' 10', ' 20', ' 30']}
```

but the last write to text file doesn't work. I want to write to the same file, but this returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ahmad/Downloads/Manraj/test.py", line 15, in <module>
     for user,score in user_scores:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

In simple words, I want the file to now show this:

```
Bob.Smith, 10, 20, 30
Andy.Singh, 25
```

How can I fix this error? Do I need to add other attributes that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things wrong with your code.

The error you're getting is because:

```
for user,score in user_scores:
```

doesn't iterate over the contents of the dictionary like you seem to think. To do that properly you'd need to use something like:

```
for user, scores in user_scores.items():
```

The other problems have to do with the file handling. By default, `open()` only opens a file only for reading. To do both you need something like a mode of `'r+'` which means reading and writing.

Also in the loop where you write lines to the file needs to handle both the case where there list of scores as well as when there's only one. To simplify things I made adding / updating entries always create a list of values, even if that list consists of only one value. This makes it possible to only have to handle scores one way — since they'll always be lists — in the formatting done in the `write()` statement used to update the file.

```
user_scores = {}

with open('Class 1.txt', 'r+') as f:
    # read existing contents
    for line in f:
        this_line = [elem.strip() for elem in line.split(",")]
        user_scores[this_line[0]] = this_line[1:]

    # add or update an entry
    username = "Andy.Singh"
    score = 25
    user_scores.setdefault(username, []).append(str(score))

    print(user_scores)

    # rewrite file
    f.seek(0)  # rewind file
    for user, scores in user_scores.items():
        f.write('{}, {}\n'.format(user, ', '.join(s for s in scores)))
```

`Class 1.txt` after running:

```
Bob.Smith, 10, 20, 30
Andy.Singh, 25
```

`Class 1.txt` after changing score added to 30 and running again:

```
Bob.Smith, 10, 20, 30
Andy.Singh, 25, 30
```

Comment: Fantastic sir! Thank you @martineau. Just one question, if I re - run the program and change the value of score to `30`, I would expect the file to read `Andy.Singh, 25, 30`, but instead, it goes `Andy.Singh,30`. Would I need to modify one line to accommodate this functionality?

Comment: Almost. The `user_scores[username] = score` line need to be changed. I also notice that the part that reads in the file wasn't stripping spaces, so they were accumulating with multiple runs. See my updated answer.

Comment: Note that with the update, the if not isinstance(scores, list): is no longer necessary since even one score will be put into a list. It would probably be better to make `user_scores` a `collections.defaultdict(list)` dictionary subclass instead of a regular dictionary then you wouldn't have to special case the adding of the first score to a new entry verses another one to an existing entry — they would both be handled with just `user_scores[username].append(str(score))`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to  use `user_scores.items()` or `user_score.iteritems()`. You'll also need to iter over your list of scores, then add `'\n'` to go to the next line:

```
for user,score in user_scores.iteritems():
    f.write(user + ' , ')
    for i in list(score): f.write(str(i) + ' , ')
    f.write('\n')
```

Also, I just realized you're writing to the same file that you're reading from, you'll need to open the file like this `with open('openfile.txt', 'r+') as f`, this will append all writing to the end (if you loop through it first). I suggest opening a new "output" file so that you don't write over any of your data.

If you want to completely write over your file, open the file again with `'w'` or `'wb'`.

Comment: when you open your file to read use `open(filename, 'r')`, when you want to write use `open(filename, 'w')`, if you want to do both at the same time use `open(filename, 'r+')`. It sounds like you are trying to read the file when it's only open to writing.

Answer (score 0):

Use to get the key and values of the dictionary in the for loop:

```
for user, score in user_scores.items():
```

If you use just user_scores in the for loop, python only use the keys of the dictionary.